# pickle requires uuid.SafeUUID

Tags: python-3.x, pickle, uuid

When reading a pickle-file I have the following problem

```
with open(source_file, "rb") as fp:
data = pickle.load(fp)

AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'SafeUUID' on <module 'uuid' from 'C:\\Program Files\\Python36\\lib\\uuid.py'>
```

I run Win7Pro with the most minimal Python configuration (Python 3.6.7 and a few libraries that should not have anything to do with this). I had this problem also with Python3.7.0 (Anaconda3.5.1, with and without virtual environment) and Pycharm2018. The above does not work from commandline either (outside PyCharm).

Running uuid.uuid4() from command line works fine.

Anyone a suggestion on how to solve this, or a workaround? Using other routines is fine as well (in that case, preferably with code)

thanks,

Andreas

Comment: I also got the exact same error. It turns out that it was due to a mismatch between the current version of the python interpreter and the version of python against which the python module I used was compiled (I recompile the cython with the right Python.h file, to solve the issue.)
So maybe try to check that the version of the library that you use match with your the version of your python interpreter.